# Squatters on x.stackexhange.com

Tags: discussion, support

I noticed that there are squatters on stackexhange.com. Is there a formal place to submit this or is this meta forum the best place? It seemed to redirect me to Amazon, so I'm guessing they are squatting on the affiliate stuff stackexchange does with Amazon.

Comment: You cant squat a sub-domain of a domain.  SE changes any Amazon link to their Amazon affiliate link.  Your question is confusing

Comment: they exploit a typo (stackex-hange instead of stackex-change). [x.stackexchange.com/](//x.stackexchange.com/) looks okay